# SFMC: API right for transitions in a workflowitems

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketingcloudapi

I would like to change the status from "Draft" to "Approved" in an approval workflow for emails.

I tried to used this api call - `POST /hub/v1/workflowitems/{workflowItemid}/transitions`

JSON body -

```
{
"transitionid" : "Approved"
}
```

In response I have -

```
{
    "message": "No roles found for the current user",
    "errorcode": 20000,
    "documentation": ""
}
```

See the documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/routes.htm#detail_TransitionWorkflowItem)

For these calls, I use a server-to-server API Package with all the possible rights.

So my question is - how to give permission to my package to change the status of the workflow approval?

EDIT:

I finally found a solution. It seems impossible to approve an email with a server to server package. So I created a Marketing Cloud App package in order to authenticate with my user and get a token with the context of my user. Also I add to modify my call on -  `POST /hub/v1/workflowitems/{workflowItemid}/transitions`

JSON Body -

```
{    
    "workflowItemId":{workflowItemid},
    "overrideNotificationId":9,     
    "transitionId":"approve" 
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Niko for the editing !

Comment: The only way I was able to do this was to add the installed package app user to the approval team

Comment: Thank you for your feed back, How did you manage to add this user in the approval Team? In the UI, i can only add users (not package) and don't find any api call for this.

Comment: I finally found a solution.
It seems impossible to approve an email with a server to server package. So I created a Marketing Cloud App package in order to authenticate with my user and get a token with the context of my user.

Also I add to modify my call on -
  `POST /hub/v1/workflowitems/{workflowItemid}/transitions`

JSON Body -

`{
    "workflowItemId":{workflowItemid},
    "overrideNotificationId":9,
    "transitionId":"approve"
}`